# Word VBA - Deleting a shape inside a specific paragraph

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to delete a picture inside a specific chapter for which I searched previously. 
Can someone point me the right way to do this...
This is the code I wrote so far.

```
    If insideparagraph Then

        'error is here
        Dim o As Word.InlineShape
        For Each o In DocPara.Range
        o.Delete
        Next

    End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have to tweak and test this

```
If insideparagraph Then

    Dim o As Word.InlineShape
    For Each o In DocPara.Range.InlineShapes
    o.Delete
    Next

End If
```